# Query to check inside List

Tags: java, c#, linq, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINRT XAML)**.

I am have a **list**:

```
List<ListType> AllRecords= new List<ListType>();
```

Class for list:

```
public class ListType
{
    public string emailID { get; set; }
    public string WorkoutID { get; set; }
}
```

Now there are many entries in this list, example:

> abc@yahoo.com, 194 abc@yahoo.com, 103 xya@nan.com, 194 xya@nan.com,203

I want to check whether a particular email has particular `WorkoutID` or not? 
example to check if  `abc@yahoo.com` has `103`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Any()`:

```
var result = AllRecords.Any(x => x.emailID == "abc@yahoo.com" && x.WorkoutID == "103");
```

Comment: ERROR: The && operator cannot be applied to operands of type bool and string

Comment: (x => x.emailID == "abc@yahoo.com" && x.WorkoutID == "103"

Comment: @AtifShabeer Glad to help.